# Python multiprocessing code using pipes hangs at first .recv() method when Pipes are generated automatically

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm writing some bogus practice code so I can implement the ideas once I have a better idea of what I'm doing. The code is designed for multiprocessing in order to reduce the runtime by splitting the stack of three arrays into several pieces horizontally that are then executed in parallel via `map_async`. However, the code seems to hang at the first `.recv()` method of a pipe, even though the `Pipe()` object is fully defined, and I'm not sure why it's doing it. If I manually define each `Pipe()` object then the code works just fine, but as soon as I iterate the process the code hangs at `sec1 = pipes[0][0].recv()`. How can I fix this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import math

num_sections = 4

pipes_send = [None]*num_sections
pipes_recv = [None]*num_sections
pipes = zip(pipes_recv,pipes_send)

for i in range(num_sections):
    pipes[i] = list(pipes[i])

for i in range(num_sections):
    pipes[i][0],pipes[i][1] = Pipe()

def f(sec_num):
    for plane in range(3):
        hist_sec[sec_num][plane] += rand_sec[sec_num][plane]
    if sec_num == 0:
        pipes[0][1].send(hist_sec[sec_num])
        pipes[0][1].close()
    if sec_num == 1:
        pipes[1][1].send(hist_sec[sec_num])
        pipes[1][1].close()
    if sec_num == 2:
        pipes[2][1].send(hist_sec[sec_num])
        pipes[2][1].close()
    if sec_num == 3:
        pipes[3][1].send(hist_sec[sec_num])
        pipes[3][1].close()


hist = np.zeros((3,512,512))
hist_sec = []
randmat = np.random.rand(3,512,512)
rand_sec = []
for plane in range(3):
    hist_div = np.array_split(hist[plane], num_sections)
    hist_sec.append(hist_div)
    randmatsplit = np.array_split(randmat[plane], num_sections)
    rand_sec.append(randmatsplit)

hist_sec = np.rollaxis(np.asarray(hist_sec),1,0)
rand_sec = np.rollaxis(np.asarray(rand_sec),1,0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = mp.Pool(num_sections)
    args = np.arange(num_sections)
    pool.map_async(f, args, chunksize=1)
    sec1 = pipes[0][0].recv()
    sec2 = pipes[1][0].recv()
    sec3 = pipes[2][0].recv()
    sec4 = pipes[3][0].recv()
    for plane in range(3):
        hist_plane = np.concatenate((sec1[plane],sec2[plane],sec3[plane],sec4[plane]),axis=0)
        hist_full.append(hist_plane)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Is this Python 2, or 3? Why are *both* tagged?

Comment: I tagged both in case there are relevant differences between the two since I will unfortunately have to implement the actual ideas into Python 3. Apologies for any confusion. This code was written in Python 2

Comment: Just use `Queue` instead of `Pipe`. Pipes are low level things, avoid if possible.

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Our code was using queues at first but I found them a little opaque and troublesome